# php get id from html select

Tags: php

my html form is bellow and process this page with add_post_process.php. In this page i insert the data to mysql database in table name "user_post"

Well, i can insert the all data to mysql database but can't insert cat_id. How can i get this cat_id from my html form? if you need add_post_process.php code then i'll post this. Thanks.

### "user_post" table structure:

post_id
user_id
subject
image
img_name
message
cat_id
cat_name
comment_count
poster
date

```
<form action="add_post_process.php" method="post" name="addpost" 
enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<select name="cat_name" class="tdpost">
<?php   
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
$cat_name = $row['cat_name'];
$cat_id = $row['cat_id'];
echo "<option value='$cat_name'>$cat_name</option>";
}
?>  
</select></td>
</tr>    
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Post" class="submit" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="reset" name="clear" value="Clear" class="submit" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: using post  you are getting values by name of the elements , what is the cat_id in that list, only the cat_name you will get from post set the $cat_id as value in select options.

Comment: if set cat_id to the value then i'll get cat_id, not get cat_name. I need both user selected cat_name with cat_id

Comment: cat_name is name of select box and it will give you the value of the selected option. to get both you need to set cat_id in some hidden element or in value itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the value of the HTML form element that is submitted - I guess you wanted to write `echo "<option value='$cat_id'>$cat_name</option>";`. Below you can find shorter and cleaner code:

```
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) : ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $row['cat_id'] . '|' . $row['cat_name'] ?>"><?php echo $row['cat_name'] ?></option>
<php endwhile ?>
```

You end up with select like this:

```
<select name="cat_name">
   <option value="1|category1">category1</option>
   <option value="2|category2">category2</option>
   <option value="3|category3">category3</option>
</select>
```

Because the whole `x|categoryx` value will be posted, it's enough to split it by `|`
Then in your **add_post_process.php** file do like this:

```
$cats = explode("|", $_POST['cat_name']);
echo $cats[0]; // cat_id
echo $cats[1]; // cat_name
```

Comment: Well, but It's send cat_id if i echo cat_id to the option value. I need both cat_id and cat_name which i send to the mysql database table column name 'cat_id' and 'cat_name'

Comment: i can't understand, please clear it more with final html and php code. Just for html select command.

Comment: well i can get cat_id with  'echo $cats[0]'. So what's the sql command. $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_post VALUES('$cats[0]', '', '',)")   Is it?