# Identify The Difference between Multiple Select Boxes with Same Name

Tags: php, forms

Perhaps what I'm trying to do is not possible, which would make sense. However, I don't know how I would be able to accomplish what I would like.

I have a conversations system set up that all works handy-dandy. However, I want to allow "Admins" to change the roles of each member of the conversation to or from "Moderator" and "Member". I have a form set up, but I don't know how I would set select boxes dynamically to apply to that particular member.

Right now, I have a table that lists each members name, all wrapped in a form, and then a select box next to it that has the option to switch their role. I gave each select box the same name because I thought that would return some Google Searches on how to do this, but since I specifically need to update the database for that particular member, I don't know how it would work.

```
<select id="' . $convorolesrow['id'] . '" name="convomemrole">
<option value="Moderator">Moderator</option>
<option value="Member">Member</option>
</select>
```

As you see, each select box has the same name of "convomemrole" and a different ID to hopefully identify the difference between the two, but that doesn't quite make sense as far as any Google Searches could lead me to.

Is this possible? If not, what is the proper way of approaching this.

Some possible ways would be to array the name and therefore use a foreach to do each select box individual, which sounds like it would work--but then how do I identify that particular select boxes ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[php get id from html select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577774/php-get-id-from-html-select)

This Q+A actually answered my question.

I am using the Array (which I already knew about) to grab all the details from each select box to use. And I'm setting the values of the each select box like so.

```
<select name="convomemrole[]">
<option value="' . $row['id'] . '|Moderator">Moderator</option>
<option value="' . $row['id'] . '|Member">Member</option>
</select>
```

And then

```
$convomemrolearray = $_POST['convomemrole'];

foreach($convomemrolearray as $convomemroles) {

$convorolesplit= explode("|", $_POST['convomemroles']);
$convorolesplit[0]; // identifier
$convorolesplit[1]; // role

#myquerieshere

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make an array in the name like:

```
<select id="' . $convorolesrow['id'] . '" name="convomemrole[]">
<option value="Moderator">Moderator</option>
<option value="Member">Member</option>
</select>
```

which will post and array containing the values of those select boxes.

Comment: At the end of my question, I already said I knew about this. I just don't see how this would help because it returns an array of all the values... but how do I "differentiate" between the select boxes. Otherwise it would just be a select box with a value with no relation to the member it is attached to.

Comment: I dont think you can differentiate. But it will be  multidimensional array like convomemrole[0] will contain the first one .... Any help?

Comment: Well, no, that's precisely what I just said I already knew about...and if this is not the way to do this, I said I didn't know any other way and was wondering if there was one.

Comment: nop,no other way. I searched for one of my project too, its not there for html.